# Managed Package installation

Tags: managed-package

We recently installed a managed package with setting 'install for all users' with limited number of licenses. Now every time a new user is created he/she is automatically assigned a licenses. Can we control this now after the managed package is installed or do we have to install the package again with 'install for admin only' setting.

Comment: please ignore the question. I was able to resolve my issue

Comment: how were you able to resolve this? Can you please post an answer, so we know.  I'm facing a similar issue.